# UTL_FILE.FREMOVE raises "file remove operation failed"

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have this code

```
BEGIN
    UTL_FILE.FREMOVE('DIR_USERS', 'user.jpg');
END;
```

It raises

```
ORA-20000: ORA-29291: file remove operation failed
ORA-6412: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 251
ORA-6512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 1230
ORA-6512: at "USERS.PKG_USERS", line 177
```

I think that the error is in the built-in function of the UTL_FILE package because when I used the function UTL_FILE.FRENAME, it also raises the same error.
What could be the problem here?

Comment: While it's always possible the UTL_FILE could have a bug such as you describe, I'm going to bet that it's something else. What happens if you try to open the file? Write to the file? Create a new file? Create and then *delete* a new file? My best guess is that the database user doesn't have permission to delete or rename files in this directory, but without actually being onsite it's kinda tough to diagnose this. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

1. Does the file exist?
2. Be aware that UTL_FILE operations are executed at the OS as the user that the oracle processes are running as, usually "oracle". So, does the "oracle" user have rwx privs on the directory containing the file? So "oracle" have rw permission on the file?

Answer (score 0):

The file could be simply hold by another program. I got the same issue:

```
SQL> begin  
  2    utl_file.FREMOVE('GK_IMP_KONN_NEW',  'PDT17_2016-05-26T11-32-38');  
  3  end;  
  4  /  
begin  
*  
FEHLER in Zeile 1:  
ORA-29291: Datei konnte nicht entfernt werden   
ORA-06512: in "SYS.UTL_FILE", Zeile 251  
ORA-06512: in "SYS.UTL_FILE", Zeile 1230  
ORA-06512: in Zeile 2
```

After uncountable tries I closed the SQL Developer and tried it again:

```
SQL> begin
2    utl_file.FREMOVE('GK_IMP_KONN_NEW',   'PDT17_2016-05-26T11-32-38');
3  end;
4  /  

PL/SQL-Prozedur erfolgreich abgeschlossen.
```

Success!